# How to filter properly with JQ

Tags: jq

I have this:

```
{
  "LaunchTemplateVersions": [
    {
      "LaunchTemplateId": "lt-xxxxxx",
      "LaunchTemplateName": "dev-xxxxxx",
      "VersionNumber": 1,
      "VersionDescription": "dev-xxxxx",
      "CreateTime": "2021-04-28T06:12:15+00:00",
      "CreatedBy": "arn:aws:sts::xxxxx",
      "DefaultVersion": true,
      "LaunchTemplateData": {
        "BlockDeviceMappings": [
          {
            "DeviceName": "/dev/xvda",
            "Ebs": {
              "Encrypted": true,
              "DeleteOnTermination": true,
              "KmsKeyId": "arn:aws:kms:xxxx",
              "SnapshotId": "snap-xxxx",
              "VolumeSize": 800,
              "VolumeType": "gp2"
            }
          }
```

and I need to get values for:

- "DeviceName"
- "KmsKeyId"
- "VolumeSize"

doing: `jq -r '.LaunchTemplateVersions[].LaunchTemplateData[].DeviceName'`

does return: *Cannot index array with string "DeviceName"*

I guess question is how can I get this right but also, ***how can I understan JQ filtering on my own, like knowing rules, etc.***.

TY

Comment: Please correct the JSON sample, and show the expected output.  As for learning jq, some resources are listed in the Tutorials section on the jq FAQ: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#related-resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the illustrative input has been corrected in the obvious way so that it is valid JSON, the invocation:

```
jq -r '
  .LaunchTemplateVersions[].LaunchTemplateData.BlockDeviceMappings[]
  | (.DeviceName, .Ebs.KmsKeyId,.Ebs.VolumeSize)' input.json
```

would yield:

```
/dev/xvda
arn:aws:kms:xxxx
800
```

#### Learning Resources

Since you asked about learning resources, let me mention that in addition to the resources mentioned on the [jq wiki](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ), you might like to browse through the guide I wrote: [A Stream-Oriented Introduction to jq](https://github.com/pkoppstein/jq/wiki/A-Stream-oriented-Introduction-to-jq).

Comment: getting:   jq: error (at <stdin>:53): Cannot iterate over null (null) - sorry cannot correct JSON sample now as it's giving me: "Suggested edit queue is full"

Comment: and thanks for the learning resources. Going through them right awy.